# Ucinet, view dataset trhough NetDraw

Tags: visualization, graph-visualization

i use `Ucinet` to manipulate some data and i would plot it with `NetDraw`, but i have a problem

after `normalization` and `affiliation` i have a dataset as this:

```
    A    B    C
A   0.0  0.5  0.5
B   0.5  0.0  0.5
C   0.5  0.5  0.0
```

In doing so, i do `Visualize->NetDraw` and, after that, `File->Open->Ucinet dataset->Network`, selecting the file above and the mode: "1-mode Network(s)". But when i try to do this i found the error "`Access violation at address 0000000040C76E in module netdraw.exe. Write of address 0000000000000.`"

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem installing the 32-bit version of Ucinet. In doing so i solve all problem encountred before.